# schema: being stripped from typeof attribute (Structured data aka RDF)

Tags: 8, rdf

I've got a field on my account, named bio. In this field, I'm manually adding the following:

```
<a href="https://www.jaypan.com/" typeof="schema:Organization>Jaypan</a>
```

However, the resulting HTML is as follows:

```
<a href="https://www.jaypan.com/" typeof="Organization>Jaypan</a>
```

I set a text filter that doesn't do anything - it allows the inputted text as-is. Everything else is exactly as I entered it into the text area. But something in Drupal is stripping out the `schema:` from the typeof property.

I've dug deep trying to figure out where this is being stripped, but I'm not finding it. Does anyone know? I'm suspecting it's something in the RDF module, but I haven't found it in there yet.

Comment: It's probably [this bug](https://www.drupal.org/node/2105841) that came off the back of https://www.drupal.org/node/2327341. Looks like the fix hasn't made its way into a stable release yet but there's a patch

Comment: Thanks Clive, however that's a D7 issue. There is a D8 issue linked here https://www.drupal.org/node/2105841 but it seems to have been committed already, and I'm still seeing the issue.

Comment: It's labelled D7 for whatever reason (maybe because it's waiting for a backport?) but if you look at the patches and discussion they're all about/for Drupal 8. The other one you linked to is in "Needs review" so I doubt it's been committed

Comment: Hi Clive - I don't know if I'm having a stupid moment here, but every patch in https://www.drupal.org/node/2105841 after #10 appears to me to be D7, and the patch in #10 doesn't work (patch fails). I tried #6 from https://www.drupal.org/node/2327341, but unfortunately it also does not work (patch fails).

Comment: Yeah that issue is very confusing, I can't follow it. Look at Wim's patches and comments (only listed under his individual posts, not at the top). Those are all for D8, but they're quite old. Can't work out what the resolution was

Comment: In the end, #69 worked for me in this one: https://www.drupal.org/node/2544110. Well kind of - one hunk failed. But it seems to be working... Anyways, thanks for your help, it got me pointed in the right direction. Much appreciated.